# htaccess 301 redirect -- remove a string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to do this htaccess 301 redirect, but I am stuck.

What I want is to remove a string in the URL, the string is: **style=5&**

I want the redirect it so all pages that may get that string in the URL will be removed. -- Thanks in advance.

FROM:

```
/viewtopic.php?style=5&f=45&t=1980&p=19136
```

TO:

```
/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=1980&p=19136
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+?&)?style=5(?:&(.*))?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^viewtopic\.php$ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2 [R=302,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks!  That fixed it!  I would have never of figured it out.  Or at least it would have taken me a lot to do so. :)

Comment: Oh, I had to change "style=" to style=5" because I am targeting that "digit".  There are other pages on my site that I want to allow.. for example: "style=1" or "style=2".  The only one I wanted removed was "style=5"